# javascript doesn't show alert message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working with radio buttons and a submit button to send the inputs of the radio buttons to a javascript file called script.js. Whenever i click the submit button without selecting data from the radio buttons, the alert message "Please fill out all fields" does not show.

my code of index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function(){
                _path = $('img').attr('src');
                _img_id = _path.replace('img/img', '');
                _img_id = _img_id.replace('.jpg', '');

                _img_id++;

                $('img').attr('src', 'img/img' + _img_id + '.jpg');
            }, 15000);
        });
    </script>    
</head>    
<body id="page-top">  
    <header>
        <h1><img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="image" style="width:738px;height:444px;"></h1>
        <hr>
        <label>Alignment: </label>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="5"> 5
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="4"> 4
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="3"> 3
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="2"> 2
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1"> 1
        <hr>
        <label>Blend: </label>
        <input type="radio" name="group2" value="5"> 5
        <input type="radio" name="group2" value="4"> 4
        <input type="radio" name="group2" value="3"> 3
        <input type="radio" name="group2" value="2"> 2
        <input type="radio" name="group2" value="1"> 1
        <hr>
        <label>Warp: </label>
        <input type="radio" name="group3" value="5"> 5
        <input type="radio" name="group3" value="4"> 4
        <input type="radio" name="group3" value="3"> 3
        <input type="radio" name="group3" value="2"> 2
        <input type="radio" name="group3" value="1"> 1
        <hr>
        <label>Overall: </label>
        <input type="radio" name="group4" value="5"> 5
        <input type="radio" name="group4" value="4"> 4
        <input type="radio" name="group4" value="3"> 3
        <input type="radio" name="group4" value="2"> 2
        <input type="radio" name="group4" value="1"> 1
        <hr>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

my code of script.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var radio1 = $("input[name=group1]:checked").val();
        var radio2 = $("input[name=group2]:checked").val();
        var radio3 = $("input[name=group3]:checked").val();
        var radio4 = $("input[name=group4]:checked").val();
        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
        var dataString = '&submit1=' + radio1 + '&submit2=' + radio2 + '&submit3=' + radio3 + '&submit4=' + radio4;

        if (radio1 == '' || radio2 == '' || radio3 == '' || radio4 == '') {
            alert("Please Fill All Fields");
        } else {
            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Im assuming you are never hitting your success callback then? Can you breakpoint to find out?

Comment: it doesn't show the "Please Fill All Fields"

Comment: Could you try using radio1 || radio2|| radio3|| radio4

Comment: That just means that the condition is not met, so the ajax call is being made. What I mean, is are you getting a success from your ajax call?

Comment: Try adding -   error: function (err) {
                        alert(err);
                    }        to your ajax object. If you get an alert displaying an error, you know the AJAX request has failed.

Comment: it is possible the values have spaces, try to trim the values to remove unnecesary spaces (like using `String.prototype.trim` method)

Comment: aqhh i just saw they are radios, check for `falsy` values as well, e.g `!radio1 || !radio2` etc..

Comment: radio1, radio2 etc values are `undefined` and `undefined != ''`

Answer (score 0):

i just saw they are radios, check for `falsy` values as well, e.g `!radio1 || !radio2` etc..

Specificaly `jQuery` tries to select a `checked` radio, but none maybe checked, so the `jQuery` object is empty, so the `.val()` will return a `falsy` value (e.g `null` or `undefined`).

Comment: `.val()` on empty jQuery objects returns `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Your html is not conform - see input tag without form tag :

```
<form onsubmit="yourfunction(); return false;"> ...
```

or use simply a tag button :

```
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test radio input for undefined like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/6/

```
if (radio1 == undefined || radio2 == undefined || radio3 == undefined || radio4 == undefined) {
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    } else {
        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.

    }
```